# Python Change variable inside a loop while looping through it

Tags: python, loops, countdown

I just startet with Python and wanted to make a little countdown app, i am able to do it with seconds but when i try to do it with minutes it just goes into the negatives, i tried it with a if statement but instead it goes into the negatives. Any Ideas? Also anything I should change to make my code cleaner? Thanks in advance :)

```
import winsound
frequency = 1000
duration = 1000

def calc(num):
    if dictionary["unit"] == "seconds":
        for i in range(num):
            print(num)
            time.sleep(1)
            num = num - 1
            if num == 0:
                winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)
    elif dictionary["unit"] == "minutes":
        num2 = 60
        sum = 60
        for i in range(num*60):
            num2 = num2 -1
            print(f"{num} Minutes {num2}")
            time.sleep(0.005)
            if num2 == 0:
                num -1
                num2 +60
            
            
            
                



def validation():
    try:
        number = int(dictionary["time"])
        if number > 0:
            calc(number)
    except ValueError:
        print("Do it again")

user = (input("Enter your Time\n"))
splitet = user.split()
dictionary = {"time": splitet[0], "unit": splitet[1]}

validation()
```

Comment: Use while loop: while i < num: ...

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the minutes to seconds and do while loop for counting down. in for range loop, `i` already acts like a count down so you don't need to check if num is 0.

```
import time
import winsound
frequency = 1000
duration = 1000

def parse_time(input_str):
  parts = input_str.split()
  if len(parts) != 2:
    raise ValueError("Wrong format.")
  try:
    number = int(parts[0])
  except ValueError:
    raise ValueError("Time is not integer")
  if number <= 0:
    raise ValueError("Negative Time")
  return number, parts[1]

def calculate_seconds(count, measure):
  if measure == "seconds":
    return count
  if measure == "minutes":
    return 60 * count

def countdown(n_sec):
  # A reversed range loop to count down
  # i will decrease from n_sec to 0 in each iteration
  for i in reversed(range(n_sec)):
    print("%d minutes %d seconds" % (i / 60, i %60))
    time.sleep(1)
  winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  # Use raw_input for raw string input.
  input_str = raw_input("Enter your Time\n")
  count, measure = parse_time(input_str)
  seconds = calculate_seconds(count, measure)
  countdown(seconds)
```